# $\exists r\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\forall s\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, $rs\in\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, examples-counterexamples, irrational-numbers

False,

If $r = 2$ and $s = \pi$ then $rs = 2\pi$ which is irrational.

Counter-example, since a rational multiplied by an irrational is always irrational. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: $\dfrac{2}{3}$ is definitely a rational number...

Comment: Huh. Yeah. Right. Don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: The product of a rational number and an irrational is not always irrational. It is irrational most of the time but there is an exception.

Comment: I assume your question title is intended to say *"$\exists r \in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\forall s\notin\mathbb{Q}$, $rs \in\mathbb{Q}$"*, is that right?

Comment: Yes, I have no idea how to put a bar over Q, ie the complement.

Comment: Ok, so the question title should be *"$\exists r\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\forall s\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, $rs\in\mathbb{Q}$"*, where $\mathbb{Q}$ denotes the complement of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ presumably, is that right? The LaTeX code for this is `$\exists r\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\forall s\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, $rs\in\mathbb{Q}$`

Comment: Thanks. I must have missed a $ somewhere.

Comment: Is $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ a classical notation for the set of irrational numbers? In my book $ \overline{\mathbb Q}$ denotes the closure of $\mathbb Q$, which is $\mathbb R$. I was confused at first.

Comment: I was lead to believe it meant the complement of Q. No I am unsure.

Comment: But $\pi$ is transcendental? It is not an element of $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$! And just because $r=2$ doesn't work some other might. Your argument: a rational times an irrational is an irrational (that only is true when the rational is non-zero) does rule out any non-zero $r$ because there are irrational numbers in $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$.

Comment: I would think that the standard meaning for $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$ is the algebraic closure of $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: The question in the title asks if there exists an $r$ with the given property. You've proved that $r = 2$ doesn't work, but what about all the other $r\not = 2$ in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 3):

Just let $r=0$, which indicates that for each $s \in \mathbb{Q}^c$, $rs=0 \in \mathbb{Q}$. But it is false when $r \neq 0$, since $s = \frac{rs}{r}$ is a rational number.

Comment: Could you explain this a little more?

Comment: In fact if $r \neq 0$ and there is a irrational number $s$ such that $rs \in \mathbb{Q}$, we can always write them as \begin{equation*} r = \frac{a}{b}, rs = \frac{c}{d}, \quad \text{ where } a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}\text{ such that } (a, b) = 1, (c, d)=1. \end{equation*} Then it is clearly that \begin{equation*}  s=\frac{rs}{r} = \frac{cb}{ad} \in \mathbb{Q}, \end{equation*}  which is a contradiction.